# Proof explanation: Intersection is trivial, then subspaces are closed

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, operator-theory

> Let $X, Y,Z$ be Banach spaces and let $T:X\to Z$ and $S:Y\to Z$ be bounded operators. If $\text{Rg }T+\text{Rg }S$ is closed and $\text{Rg }T\cap\text{Rg }S=\{0\}$, then $\text{Rg }T$ and $\text{Rg }S$ are closed.

**Proof:** Let $Q:X\times Y\to X\times Y$ be a projection onto $Y$ and define $R:X\times Y\to Z$ as $R(x,y)=Tx+Sy$. Let $U:=\text{Rg }T, V:=\text{Rg }S$. Then $$R^{-1}(U)=(RQ)^{-1}(U\cap V)=(RQ)^{-1}\{0\},$$
so $R^{-1}(U)$ is closed. Moreover, $R$ has closed range and $\ker R\subseteq R^{-1}(U)$. Therefore $U$ is closed. Similarly, $V$ is closed.

> I want to understand how it is concluded that $U$ is closed from the previous facts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $R: X\times Y\to \text{Rg }T+\text{Rg }S$ is onto. Hence the induced operator $R_/:(X\times Y)/ \ker R\to \text{Rg }T+\text{Rg }S$ is a bijection. By bounded inverse theorem, it follows that $R_/$ is a homeomorphism. Using $R_/^{-1}\{U\}=(RQ)_/^{-1}\{0\}$, it follows that $U$ is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Hints: $R((R^{-1}(U))^{c})=U^{c}$. By Open Mapping Theorem $R$ maps open sets to open sets. Conclude that $U^{c}$ is open.

Comment: Where is $\ker R\subseteq R^{-1}(U)$ used?

Comment: @Guest The given proof seems to lack clarity. I have given an independent proof.